# How to use java to get data in JSON

Tags: java, json

I want to get all the html instructions data (from routes > legs > steps > html_instruction).

I get a null return in this code. I dont know how to fix the problem. Could someone teach me how to fix it?

```
String final_json = buffer.toString();

JSONObject parent_object = new JSONObject(final_json);
JSONArray parent_array_routes = parent_object.getJSONArray("routes");
JSONArray legs = parent_array_routes.getJSONArray(2);
JSONArray steps = legs.getJSONArray(8);

StringBuffer html_instructions = new StringBuffer();

for(int i = 0; i<steps.length();i++){
    JSONObject htm = steps.getJSONObject(i);
    html_instructions.append(htm.getString("html_instructions") + "\n");
}
```

JSON

```
Response
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJyYfhZ79ZwokRMtXcL6CYxkA",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJ8YWMWnz4wokRCOVf1CcJCbY",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 40.8171321,
               "lng" : -73.99449150000001
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 40.7416627,
               "lng" : -74.0728354
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2015 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "9.7 mi",
                  "value" : 15653
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "25 mins",
                  "value" : 1480
               },
               "end_address" : "1 MetLife Stadium Dr, East Rutherford, NJ 07073, USA",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 40.814505,
                  "lng" : -74.07272910000002
               },
               "start_address" : "75 Ninth Ave, New York, NY 10011, USA",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7428759,
                  "lng" : -74.00584719999999
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "440 ft",
                        "value" : 134
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 34
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7422925,
                        "lng" : -74.004457
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esoutheast\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eW 16th St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eNinth Ave\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "_rtwFpgubMtBuG"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7428759,
                        "lng" : -74.00584719999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "49 ft",
                        "value" : 15
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 29
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7421744,
                        "lng" : -74.0045361
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at the 1st cross street onto \u003cb\u003eNinth Ave\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "intwFz~tbMVN"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7422925,
                        "lng" : -74.004457
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "226 ft",
                        "value" : 69
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 24
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7416627,
                        "lng" : -74.0049708
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e to stay on \u003cb\u003eNinth Ave\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-slight-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "qmtwFj_ubMDN@@?@JFXP`@VTN"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7421744,
                        "lng" : -74.0045361
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 mi",
                        "value" : 266
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 74
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.74282729999999,
                        "lng" : -74.00773459999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eW 15th St\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "kjtwF`bubMIVeBlFEN{A|EWr@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7416627,
                        "lng" : -74.0049708
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "1.1 mi",
                        "value" : 1815
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "6 mins",
                        "value" : 349
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7571135,
                        "lng" : -73.9973176
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at the 1st cross street onto \u003cb\u003e10th Ave\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "uqtwFhsubMo@c@oA{@iAw@A?EEc@YwBuAaAq@o@c@gBiAMIsBoAmA{@m@a@eCaBcCaB}BuA{ByAyB{A{ByAyByA_C{AYU}AaA{ByAUMCC]UcAs@eC_BeC_B{ByA{ByAyByA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.74282729999999,
                        "lng" : -74.00773459999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 mi",
                        "value" : 273
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 59
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7559092,
                        "lng" : -73.99449150000001
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eW 38th St\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "}jwwFfrsbMzA}E@CNe@Tu@d@uAHYHU@AHWDM^iA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7571135,
                        "lng" : -73.9973176
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "377 ft",
                        "value" : 115
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 38
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7550018,
                        "lng" : -73.9951569
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at the 1st cross street onto \u003cb\u003eNinth Ave\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "mcwwFp`sbMtBtA~@n@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7559092,
                        "lng" : -73.99449150000001
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.1 mi",
                        "value" : 226
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 39
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7560886,
                        "lng" : -73.9950563
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Slight \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto the \u003cb\u003eLincoln Tunnel\u003c/b\u003e ramp to \u003cb\u003eNew Jersey\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "w}vwFvdsbMJb@@D?D?D@D?DAB?D?DADADADYz@AFCBA@ABCBC@C@C?A?C?C?C?CACCECMUo@eAa@m@EIEECGEEGEEECEII"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7550018,
                        "lng" : -73.9951569
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "112 ft",
                        "value" : 34
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 6
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7563822,
                        "lng" : -73.9949785
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Merge onto \u003cb\u003eNY-495 W\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "merge",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "qdwwFbdsbMECECCAEAEAE?EAE?E?E?"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7560886,
                        "lng" : -73.9950563
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.9 mi",
                        "value" : 1453
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 mins",
                        "value" : 124
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7631296,
                        "lng" : -74.00948579999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at the fork to stay on \u003cb\u003eNY-495 W\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eEntering New Jersey\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "fork-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "kfwwFrcsbMG?E?C@E@E@E@E@EBGBWNEBGDCBMLEDIJ?@IJADEFe@|@?BkBtDCBQ^ABABEFe@bAIRMb@KXGPWx@Wx@Oj@Ib@G\\Kl@CVALCJCL{BzGoA~DoA|DK`@ABUt@[~@CH_@hAcMz`@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7563822,
                        "lng" : -73.9949785
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "2.8 mi",
                        "value" : 4516
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "5 mins",
                        "value" : 301
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7767179,
                        "lng" : -74.042813
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continue onto \u003cb\u003eNJ-495 W\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "qpxwFh~ubMsJpZsJpZeAbD[rAOt@Ij@E\\?@Cf@A\\?v@@j@@D?BB^D\\BJBL?B@FFVBFBHH\\P`@Tf@Z^X^jAx@HJFLFHJJp@h@`@Zf@`@VPZNb@P^Hl@TVBHDJFJDNJJFJJNJLJPLHHDDHDDBFDHBFBH@H?F?J?HAJAJCHCJEJEJGJGJIHIJKFMHMDKFODODOBQ@O@Q@S?QAO?QCOCQCOEQGOGMIOGMIIGIIGKIIGSISKm@Wg@Qg@Sk@Qi@Qi@Qi@Og@Me@Ke@Mo@Ki@Kg@Ge@Ie@G]C[CM?S?S@QBSDODODMFMDMHML_@^KHINIJGLIPITUl@cIxUMV?BSj@_@lAi@hBEH?@s@bCg@dBQp@?BKXSp@Yt@Wt@_@bAsBhFSf@CDiBzEi@rAYr@eArCSh@Qf@M^Od@Qj@_ErOIXGXIXIXGZK^K`@YbAI\\Sz@m@bCo@`CQp@Mh@Of@Sz@M`@Sx@g@dBIX"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7631296,
                        "lng" : -74.00948579999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.3 mi",
                        "value" : 435
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 21
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7797406,
                        "lng" : -74.04597939999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e at the fork to continue on \u003cb\u003eNJ-3 W\u003c/b\u003e, follow signs for \u003cb\u003eNew Jersey 3 W\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eGarden State Parkway\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eSecaucus\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "fork-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "oe{wFpn|bMc@fAEJIRIPKPKPMPOROPOPONOVIHy@|@oBnBUTURSPc@Ze@Zg@XaAb@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7767179,
                        "lng" : -74.042813
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "2.2 mi",
                        "value" : 3560
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 mins",
                        "value" : 141
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8041562,
                        "lng" : -74.0717843
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e to stay on \u003cb\u003eNJ-3 W\u003c/b\u003e, follow signs for \u003cb\u003eNew Jersey 3 W\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eClifton\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "keep-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "kx{wFjb}bMMJGDEBEBIDeA`@m@R{@VyA`@aB\\qAXiB`@uCl@A?A?QDs@NSFuAXwBf@{@Za@Nm@T_@NYLi@VmAl@gAp@m@`@}@l@QPA@IDA@[XA@_@Ze@`@ONA@i@h@STu@v@eApA}@pAq@bAwAzBgC~DaBhCs@lAq@|@YZo@hA{@pA_A~AsArB{@rAuAvBq@jAUZABA@qFjIe@t@mDpFOVcCvDgElGQVkC|D?@yBhDcDbFy@lAsCfEyGzJ{BdDUZsAzB"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.7797406,
                        "lng" : -74.04597939999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 mi",
                        "value" : 249
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 13
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8062905,
                        "lng" : -74.07245929999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Take the \u003cb\u003eNJ-120 N\u003c/b\u003e exit toward \u003cb\u003eE Rutherford\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "ramp-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "_q`xFrcbcMSBA?CBIFOLi@^SJSJOFQFSDODUD]Ba@@g@@_BF"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8041562,
                        "lng" : -74.0717843
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "410 ft",
                        "value" : 125
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 6
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.807415,
                        "lng" : -74.07250909999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Keep \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e, follow signs for \u003cb\u003eState Route 503 N\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eNew Jersey 120 N\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eWashington Avenue\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eMoonachie\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003ePaterson Plank Road\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "keep-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "i~`xFzgbcMaFH"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8062905,
                        "lng" : -74.07245929999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.5 mi",
                        "value" : 869
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 38
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8145647,
                        "lng" : -74.06878929999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continue onto \u003cb\u003eNJ-120 N\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "keaxFdhbcMc@@o@@i@Au@Cg@GaAMuA_@kBk@s@UOGeA_@SIu@[i@Uc@SyAs@o@_@eBeAs@e@i@a@}C_CqBeBA?OM?AAA_@["
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.807415,
                        "lng" : -74.07250909999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 mi",
                        "value" : 339
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 16
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8170874,
                        "lng" : -74.0665298
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continue straight onto \u003cb\u003eWashington Ave\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "straight",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "_rbxF|pacMm@c@}FcFi@g@SQkB_BA??AA?KK?AAAA?IIEE"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8145647,
                        "lng" : -74.06878929999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.2 mi",
                        "value" : 358
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 38
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8143541,
                        "lng" : -74.0648063
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003ePaterson Plank Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "yacxFxbacMESAK?G?EBKBQPIFG@ALEPIxDwAp@YhAc@LEr@WFCNG~@[VK"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8170874,
                        "lng" : -74.0665298
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "79 ft",
                        "value" : 24
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 4
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8141899,
                        "lng" : -74.06498189999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eN Connection Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "upbxF`x`cMTVHH"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8143541,
                        "lng" : -74.0648063
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.1 mi",
                        "value" : 177
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 25
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8138003,
                        "lng" : -74.06693709999999
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eN Connection Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "uobxFby`cMFHFFFHPPDzATtDFfA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8141899,
                        "lng" : -74.06498189999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.3 mi",
                        "value" : 548
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 73
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8149711,
                        "lng" : -74.0728354
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Continue straight onto \u003cb\u003eRd D\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "straight",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "gmbxFjeacMDjA@X@L?DAH?HAHAFAJCHCHCHCFS^Yf@Yp@_@|@ABO\\CHw@lBQb@Q`@AH?BAB?DGRIRGTGZADCJCRCTA^?V@VBVBZF`@R~@Df@Bd@Bn@?^"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8138003,
                        "lng" : -74.06693709999999
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "174 ft",
                        "value" : 53
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 28
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.814505,
                        "lng" : -74.07272910000002
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eMetLife Stadium Dr\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eDestination will be on the right\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "qtbxFfjbcMf@AHAFA^MBA"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 40.8149711,
                        "lng" : -74.0728354
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  }
               ],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "_rtwFpgubMtBuGVNFPfAr@TNIVkB|FsBpG_C_BqA}@mGeEwH_FsDcCaGwDkNiJsJmG_SoMyByAzA}EPi@nA{Dp@qBtDdCLh@@VCT_@nAKLMBOAIG}@{Aq@eAWWOMIEWEY?UDYJi@\\]^w@|AcC|Ew@bBy@hCg@dBQ`AU~A_ChH_D|J_AzCc@rAwXl|@yLt_@k@hCSrBAtABp@LlALp@FPZ~@Tf@Z^X^jAx@PXRTrCxB~@`@lA^`@HVLv@j@n@h@`@Rb@Dl@Gl@WVQTU^w@PaA@gAKcAMa@Q]c@i@}@g@iDoAeDaAeDq@qC]i@Cg@@eAT[L[Vk@h@SZQ^_@bAeJ`XoAbEmB~GqAvDkDzIsFvNcAvCcFrRkBnHcE`Pq@~Bi@rAk@hA}@hA_@f@cAfAoDjDiAv@iB|@a@XoAf@iBj@yA`@aB\\{Dz@yCl@yA\\mE`A}Aj@qCjAuC~AkBnA_@ZcBxAoApA{BhCoBtCuJrOkAxAkBzCeH~KkAlBeMrR{I|M}CtEyBjD}EpHmLbQ{BdDiBvCUBMJy@l@g@VeAZs@HiABuKT_BEiBUaEkAcA]oCeAmAi@iCsAyCkBgEaDcCuBa@]kHgGkDyCQQOOG_@Fk@h@YfI_DxAi@vAg@^`@h@l@h@dL@v@Ef@Od@m@fAy@nBmAxCc@dAALAHQf@Qv@G^Et@@n@Fr@Z`BHlABnAp@Cj@Q"
         },
         "summary" : "NJ-495 W and NJ-3 W",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: but if i changed to  `JSONArray steps = legs.getJSONArray("steps");` it wont allow, it said that `getJSONArray (int)` cannot be applied to `(java.lang.string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample JSON `routes` and `legs` are actually arrays of objects. So to access anything inside, you first have to get an array element and then can access a property of the object by its name.

```
JSONArray legs = parent_array_routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs");
JSONArray steps = legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String final_json = buffer.toString();

JSONObject parent_object = new JSONObject(final_json);
JSONArray parent_array_routes = parent_object.getJSONArray("routes");
JSONArray legs = parent_array_routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs");
JSONObject temp= legs.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray steps =temp.getJSONArray("steps");

StringBuffer html_instructions = new StringBuffer();

for(int i = 0; i<steps.length();i++){
JSONObject htm = steps.getJSONObject(i);
html_instructions.append(htm.getString("html_instructions") + "\n");
}
```

should work this way ..